# Linux Mint: FTDI USB to Serial Adapter not working

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, serial-port

Kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.4.8 tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: Moher dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21 Vanessa base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy

I have a FTDI USB To Serial Adapter but it is not working despite that it should work out of the box on Linux Mint.

I tried dmesg:

```
dmesg |grep -i FTDI^C
6370.174721] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 6370.181796] ftdi_sio 1-4:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 6370.183103] usb 1-4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to
ttyUSB4
[ 6373.876084] usb 1-4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while
'brltty' sets config #1
[ 6373.877490] ftdi_sio ttyUSB4: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now
disconnected from ttyUSB4
[ 6373.877559] ftdi_sio 1-4:1.0: device disconnected
```

It conntects to port ttyUSB4 but disconnects immedeatly

Comment: Yes, it should just work. When they don't it's time to consider whether or not the device is either defective or a counterfeit (most likely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at brltty, it is a known issue. That is a controller for a braille interface. Purging brltty and a restart fixes this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this myself in the linux mint forums but that was the correct answer. I forgot to update this thread...

Comment: Bob, you are my hero! All my USB ports failed, both those from the mainboard and those from a hub. Using Linux Mint 21 Mate, fully up to date.
Uninstalling brltty and everything works again! If this is a known issue, why is it still present on latest Ubuntu and Mint?